# Qt C++ event on button clicked

Tags: c++, qt, qpushbutton, qtstylesheets

I am writing an Application using the Qt framework.  I am using a custom CSS file to style my widgets and components like so:

```
  QPushButton:checked#switchButtonConsole, QPushButton:checked#switchButtonList, QPushButton:checked#switchButtonStats {                                                    
      background: qlineargradient(spread:reflect, x1:1, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 #151513, stop:1 #101010);                                                                    
      border-right: 1px solid #2E2E26;                                                                                                                                        
      padding: 5px;                                                                                                                                                           
      color: #94948E;                                                                                                                                                         
  }
```

I have different CSS style depending on which state the button is in.  Whether it is checked or unchecked.

I have 3 buttons and by default the first button is set to checked, the others are set to unchecked. Here is the code that I use to set the state of the button:

```
void MainWindow::on_switchButtonConsole_clicked() {                                                                                                                            
     ui->mainStack->setCurrentIndex(3);                                                                                                                                    

    if(!isChecked(ui->switchButtonConsole)) {                                                                                                                                  
        ui->switchButtonConsole->setChecked(true);                                                                                                                             
    };                                                                                                                                                                    

};
```

The problem I am having is that if I click on another button (remember, I have a function like the one above for each button) the previous button pressed will remain in the checked state and therefore the checked state style will remain.  So if I click on all 3 buttons it looks like they are checked.
I can't seem to figure out how to set the previous button pressed to the unchecked state, so that is only applies to checked state style to the button I CURRENTLY pressed and sets the unchecked style to the rest of the buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strait solution here is to add all three buttons to QButtonGroup and set it to exclusive. This way Qt will automagically do what you want.